# sudo for only ufw?

Tags: sudoers

I want to allow the johnuser sudo access for just the ufw command.  Is this the appropriate statement to write into /etc/sudoers ?

```
johnuser    ALL=(ALL) /bin/ufw
```

I'd try this right away only I don't have access to the server.  I'm instructing someone else how to do it via email.   One thing hte other person said is that /bin/ufw doesn't exist.   If that's the case, will that be a problem?  Or how do you determine where ufw is?

Comment: do NOT directly edit /etc/sudoers.....use the visudo command!

Comment: oops i just did it and it's working right now.  DO i need to go back and revert my changes?

Comment: if it works no problem....if it doesn't then do it.  visudo does syntax checking and prevents you from having a broken /etc/sudoers file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system `ufw` is in `/usr/sbin`, so your `sudoers` line should look like

```
johnuser    ALL=(root) /usr/sbin/ufw
```

If you know that `ufw` is on the system but you don't know where it is, then do

```
# which ufw
```

as root.